# The numerical solution of Van der Pol's equation does not show chaotic behavior as expected.

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, truncation-error

I post this question again with more details :

For a bachelor's work we have to study the chaotic behavior shown in the numerical solution of the driven van der pol oscillator as a function of the length of the Runge-Kutta step size.
$$
 y'' - \mu (1 - y^2)* y' + y = f(x)
$$

My problem is that I can't find out for which parameter $\mu$ and function $f(x)$ this equation shows chaotic behavior, and what is the process to find these specific parameters?

**By "chaotic behavior" I mean:**

**a small variation in the step length has a large variation in the topology of the solution.**

I'll give you a little graphic of my current issue:

| graphical representation of the two numerical solutions with two different step lengths |
| --- |
| [image: graphical representation of the two numerical solutions with two different step lengths] |

The blue curve corresponds to a step size of $h=0.0089$.
While for the orange one the step size is $h=0.0037$.

The equation that has been solved numerically corresponds to:
$$
 y'' - \mu (1 - y^2)* y' + y = A*sin(\omega*t)
$$
with: $$\omega = \frac{2*\pi}{10},A=1.2, \mu = 8.53$$

and according [to this page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator) (in the chapter "Forced Van der Pol oscillator") the solution should be chaotic, therefore sensitive to the step length. But as you can see the two solutions overlap and are not distinguishable. I can't find out why.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: The region around the unforced limit cycle is attracting, this remains also true for small forcings. This has as consequence that the local error terms will also oscillate, thus mostly cancel over each cycle. The expected error is consequently in the size of $h^4$ and almost surely smaller than $Th^4$. For step sizes $<0.01$ this gives an error of $10^{-8}$ to at worst $10^{-5}$ for the time interval $T=700$ in the plot. These errors are not visible in a plot of the solution, at best you can see there relative errors of $10^{-2}$. Try again with step sizes in the scale of $0.1$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but the step is too small and the solution becomes "squared". My aim is instead to study solutions that seem right (not squared therefore) with a specific step length, but that if it is reduced, to get a bigger precision, they become totally another function.
I also tried to use the function $$\frac{\mu}{8}*sin(3*t)$$as driving function (which you suggested in the previous answer). But I always get the same result, i.e. no change in the topology of the solution despite the length of the step changes a lot

Comment: In the [mentioned answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3187568/115115) I made a sign error in the nonlinear term so that the computed solutions are time-reversed towards the usual equation. The forcing with period $3$ was prescribed by the question there. The chaos in the wiki links is the pattern of the resulting periods which resembles the devils staircase.  This is more in the direction of self-similar patterns than chaotic attractors like in the Lorenz system.