# Stuck while finding all periods of non-autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

> Consider the non-autonomous equation
> $$x''+ x = \varepsilon f(x,x') + \varepsilon(\cos(2\pi t)+\sin(3\pi t)),$$
> Where $x=x(t)$ and the prime denotes differentiation with respect to $t$. Assume that this equation has (a) periodic solution(s). What are the possible periods?

I know how to tackle this problem.
Let $x=\phi(t)$ be a periodic solution of the equation. Hence, $\phi$ satisfies:
\begin{equation} 
    \phi(t)''+\phi(t) = \epsilon f(\phi(t),\phi(t)') + \epsilon(\cos(2\pi t) + \sin(3\pi t)).
\end{equation}
Since $\phi$ is periodic, there is a $T>0$ such that $\phi(t) = \phi(t+T)$. It follows that $\phi(t)' = \phi(t+T)'$, $\phi(t)'' = \phi(t+T)''$ and $f(\phi(t),\phi(t)') = f(\phi(t+T),\phi(t+T)')$. We know that $\phi(t+T)$ is also a solution to the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
    \phi(t+T)''+\phi(t+T) = \varepsilon f(\phi(t+T),\phi(t+T)') + \varepsilon(\cos(2\pi (t+T)) + \sin(3\pi (t+T))).
\end{equation}
If we subtract the first from the second, and take the periodicity into account, we are left with:
\begin{equation*}
    0 = \cos(2\pi (t+T)) + \sin(3\pi (t+T)) - \cos(2\pi t) - \sin(3\pi t).
\end{equation*}
My problem is that I do not know how to proceed. I feel that it is easy and that I somehow need to  use addition rules, but I do not know how to solve this equation. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See also a similar earlier problem (with some unresolved discussions about some details): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186028/what-are-the-possible-periods-of-the-solutions-to-this-ode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use adition formulas and the linear independece of sine and cosine.
You have:
\begin{equation*}
    0 = \cos(2\pi (t+T)) + \sin(3\pi (t+T)) - \cos(2\pi t) - \sin(3\pi t).
\end{equation*}

With adition formulas we get
\begin{equation*}
    0 = \cos(2\pi t)\cos(2\pi T)-\sin(2\pi t)\sin(2\pi T) + \sin(3\pi t)\cos(3\pi T)+\sin(3\pi T)\cos(3\pi t) - \cos(2\pi t) - \sin(3\pi t).
\end{equation*}
Isolating
\begin{equation*}
    0 = \cos(2\pi t)(\cos(2\pi T)- 1)-\sin(2\pi t)\sin(2\pi T) + \sin(3\pi t)(\cos(3\pi T)- 1)+\sin(3\pi T)\cos(3\pi t)  .
\end{equation*}
As $\cos(2\pi t)$,  $\sin(2\pi t)$, $\sin(3\pi t)$ and $\cos(3\pi t)$ are linearly indepentent, we need:
$$(\cos(2\pi T)- 1)=0$$
$$\sin(2\pi T)=0$$
$$(\cos(3\pi T)- 1)=0$$
$$\sin(3\pi T)=0.$$
From this we get that $T$ must be a even interger.